# Axe bounces all the way back

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

Here's something I can't quite understand:

The video [Woman Dodges Death in Axe Throwing Accident](https://www.insideedition.com/woman-dodges-death-axe-throwing-accident-52027) shows a woman throwing an axe at a wall, and the axe bounces back all the way — how's that possible?

Is this related to conservation of momentum — what's the right physics explanation for this phenomenon?

Comment: The axe wouldn't have killed her, but it could have produced a cut that required 10 or so stitches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The axe bounces back, but it is considerably slower than the speed at which it was thrown, meaning it has lost energy as it bounced off the floor/wall. Collisions of macroscopic objects are almost always inelastic, meaning they are accompanied by at least some "loss" of energy.

The precise motion of the axe depends on a number of things, including the composition of the axe and the floor/wall and the way it was thrown. It may be complicated to predict the trajectory since the axe is an extended body that also rotates as it moves, but it is entirely possible for the axe to reach a greater height than the one from which it was released. However, the total mechanical energy (potential plus kinetic) upon its return must always be less than the initial value.

Comment: Plus momentum is conserved by the wall/earth